# Delphi Video freezes

Tags: android, delphi, video, camera, firemonkey

In firemonkey writes apps for android.
I have a problem with displaying the image.
Terribly stutters image

```
procedure TForm1.CameraComponent1SampleBufferReady(Sender: TObject;
  const ATime: Int64);
var
  bmp: TBitmap;
begin
  bmp := TBitmap.Create(0, 0);
  CameraComponent1.SampleBufferToBitmap(bmp, True);
  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      Image1.Bitmap.Assign(bmp);
    end
  );
  bmp.Free;
end;
```

Why are you painting hangs?
Tests on the device Xperia m2
When compiling the wine works well

Comment: Does `onSampleBufferReady` handler execute in additional thread ???

Comment: Probably not. It's like I had to do was not to lag. How to solve IT?

Comment: Is TImage designed to be a video player?

Comment: Also, "probably not" is no use. You have to know what you are doing. Why call Synchronize if not in a thread?

Comment: And how does the official sample perform? http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/42558

Comment: I'm stumped over the use of Synchronize as well.

Comment: I was doing this too David Heffernan and further the same